# C# WCF HTTP Endpoint - Is there a way to markup a webservice method to say use Kerberos

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf, kerberos

I have a C# WCF HTTP Endpoint, I would like specific methods to request Kerberos. Is there a way to markup a webservice method to say use Kerberos.

I have Windows Authentication setup on my WCF web service but for a specific method, I would like to pass Kerberos instead of NTLM.

Is it possible to decorate a method stub in the interface to tell the web service to request Kerberos for this method only?

Does the Authentication model used need to be set for the entire web service as opposed to specified for individual method/endpoints in the web service?